# Reactjs add a number to a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

say I had a Reactjs state that was organized like so:

```
getInitialState: function(){
return {food: ''}
}
```

How would I add conditional number values to that state? Say something like:

```
firstset: function(){
this.setState({food: +9});
}
```

And

```
secondset:function(){
this.setState({food: +10});
}
```

I would like to know how I would go about iterating these numbers to the state of 'food' when the `firstset` function is activated, along with the `secondset`. So the consequence of activating them both once is `9+10`, which would make `food: 19`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the previous state while setting it:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    food: 0
  }
}

firstSet: function() {
  this.setState({
    food: this.state.food + 9
  })
}

secondSet: function() {
  this.setState({
    food: this.state.food + 10
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, food should be initially set as Number:

```
getInitialState: function(){
  return {
    food: 0
  }
}
```

Then to add some value to something you need the value.. so just take the `this.state.food` value..

```
incBy: function(value) {
   this.setState({
     food: this.state.food + value
   });
}
```